# fatal error: sys/sysctl.h: No such file or directory compilation error, why this error?

Tags: c

```
/home/william/Desktop/BlitzMax/mod/brl.mod/platform.mod/glue.c:24:10: fatal error: sys/sysctl.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <sys/sysctl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Ubuntu 22.04. on Ubuntu 18 I don't have this error as far as I know, going to test that but I want to use the latest release. um.. another user tried to replicate the error on a virtual machine using the same ISO version but didn't have an issue compiling.

Can I get some help, what could it be? A lib dependency?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The Linux sysctl interface has been deprecated for some time and [was removed altogether in glibc-2.32](https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=changelog&l=glibc&v=2.32), so likely the software that you are trying to build needs to be updated/ported for newer kernels.

Comment: im trying to build modules in blitzmax, it uses c/c++ in its modules as far as i know.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add that information to your question

Comment: Redo your copy/paste into the question with the code, because the line breaks did NOT make it into your code in the question.  I rolled back your code edit because it was entirely unreadable and unable to be compiled in the failed copy/paste state it was in